# Migrating .NET core 2.0 IActionSelectorDecisionTreeProvider is missing

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I'm migrating my .NET Core web api from 1.1.2 to 2.0 and I come accross error at:

```
app.UseMvc();
```

I get error:

```
System.TypeLoadException: 'Could not load type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.IActionSelectorDecisionTreeProvider' from assembly 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'.'
```

Packages that I have installed:

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.All v2.0
Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration v2.0
Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.CommandLine v2.0
Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug v2.0
Microsoft.Extensions.Options v2.0
Microsoft.NETCore.App v2.0
```

I have found [this](https://github.com/Microsoft/aspnet-api-versioning/issues/154) and [this](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/4802) github error report but there is no mentioned about

```
app.UseMvc();
```

Has anyone come across this issue to?

Comment: I believe Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.IActionSelectorDecisionTre‌​eProvider was removed in core 2.0

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar problem and I resolved by making sure that all the references to `Microsoft.AspNetCore.*` were updated to version `2.0.0`.

You can do this by executing the following:

```
dotnet add package Microsoft.AspNetCore.....
```

If the package is already part of your project, the `add` command will update it.